# how to assign a value from scanner to a object?

Tags: java, eclipse, class, object, tostring

I am trying to assign a value to class object from a `Scanner`. I don't want to use `Teacher a = new Teacher("Ali","SCF333",'M');` because its already setted, I want the user to input the data

This is my driver class:

```
public class TeacherDriver {
    public static void main(String[]args){


        String data;
        Teacher a = new Teacher();



        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter Employee Name: ");
        data=input.nextLine();
        a.setEmpName();
        System.out.println("Please enter Employee ID: ");
        data2=input.nextLine();
        a.setEmpID();
        System.out.println("Please enter Employee Gender: ");
        data3=input.nextLine();
        a.setGender();


        System.out.println(a.toString());


    }
}
```

and this is the class:

```
public class Teacher {
    private String empID;
    private String empName;
    private Address address;
    private char gender; 
    private String [] Subject;

    Teacher(){

    }

    Teacher(String empName){
        this.empName=empName;
    }

    Teacher(String empName,String empID){
        this.empName=empName;
        this.empID=empID;
    }

    Teacher(String empName,String empID,char gender){
        this.empName=empName;
        this.empID=empID;
        this.gender=gender;
    }

    Teacher(String empName,String empID,char gender,Address address){

        this.empName=empName;
        this.empID=empID;
        this.gender=gender;
        this.address=address;
    }

    Teacher(String empName,String empID,char gender,Address address,String[]Subject){

        this.empName=empName;
        this.empID=empID;
        this.gender=gender;
        this.address=address;
        this.Subject=Subject;   
    }

    public void setEmpID(){
        this.empID=empID;
    }

    public void setEmpName(){
        this.empName=empName;
    }

    public void setGender(){
        this.gender=gender;
    }

    public String getEmpID(){
        return empID;
    }

    public String getEmpName(){
        return empName;
    }

    public char getGender(){
        return gender;
    }

    public Address getAddress(){
        return address;
    }

    public String[] getSubject(){
        return Subject;
    }

     public String toString()
     {
         String viewteacher = new String("Name: " + empName + "\nID: "+ empID +"\nGender: "+ gender + "\nSubjects: "+ Subject); 
          return viewteacher;
     }
}
```

Comment: `Teacher t = new Teacher(data,data2,data3.charAt(0));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is wrong way of creating setter methods, Here you are just setting your instance variable `empName` to same instance variable `empName`.

```
public void setEmpName(){
    this.empName=empName;
}
```

You have to pass argument to set method, and then that argument will set.

```
public void setEmpName(String empName){
    this.empName=empName;
}
```

`TeacherDriver` class will need to be modified as follows,

```
  System.out.println("Please enter Employee Name: ");
  data=input.nextLine();
  a.setEmpName(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you exactly want but here you go,

```
System.out.println("Please enter Employee Name: ");
data=input.nextLine();
a.setEmpName(data);
System.out.println("Please enter Employee ID: ");
data2=input.nextLine();
a.setEmpID(data2);
System.out.println("Please enter Employee Gender: ");
// Assuming that the user is entering correct data
data3=input.nextLine();
a.setGender(data3.charAt(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Create object after getting input.

```
      a.setEmpName();
      a.setEmpID();
```

Above calls will not set the value as it dont have any parameter been passed to set. Modify the Teacher object creation  as below

```
    Teacher a = new Teacher(data1,data2,data3);
```

Include the  above call after  storing input  in the data1,data2 and data3 variables.

Answer (score 0):

Your setters do not have any parameters passed to set the values. Below's how they should typically look

```
public void setSomething(String something) {
    this.something=something;
}
```

and then you invoke them thus:

```
MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
myObject.setSomething(scanner.nextLine());
```

You can check javadocs for how Scanner works